# Google Analytics Realtime report shows no data for GWT Application

Tags: gwt, google-analytics, google-drive-realtime-api

I've just created an account to use to track my GWT application and in the process of adding tracking code so I'm looking for some real time feedback on if any of my tracking code is working properly. My application is not public (deployed on my local machine with firewalls), and I haven't seen any javascripts error after adding the tracking code. However when I hit my website on my machine there's no indication in the realtime report that there's an active user, page viewed or any data at all. In my application html I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Account number']);//I have real account number in my project
      _gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 0]);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageView', 'name']);




      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();


    </script>
```

which should at least set up page views tracking for me.

I'm assuming that Google Analytics don't need access to my website since I'm the one sending. However I'm new to both GWT and Google Analytics so I could be completely wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageView', 'name']);
```

by this one:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'name']);
```

Note the lowercase "v" in `_trackPageview`. Method names are case-sensitive ([reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#CommonPitfalls)).